# Differential length of a logarithmic spiral

Tags: geometry, physics, polar-coordinates

I am working on a problem that asks to find the magnetic field at the origin of a logarithmic spiral $r = e^\theta$ from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi$, where the angle $\theta$ is measured counterclockwise from the positive x axis.

I was able to do some research and found the following information about the curve.

[image]

[image]

I know that the tan() of the angle between a radial line and the tangent is 1 in this case because the coefficient on the exponent is 1.

My question is how the differential length $ds$ was determined? Also, I have no idea how $tan \beta = r d\theta / dr$. Can anyone help explain the geometry on this problem to me?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

$dr$ is the infinitesimal change in the radial direction while $r d\theta$ is the corresponding change in the perpendicular direction. The arc length is therefore:
$$
ds = \sqrt{dr^2 + (rd\theta)^2} = \\
\sqrt{1 + \left(r\frac{d\theta}{dr}\right)^2}dr
$$
 Also, $tan\beta$ is the ratio of tangential to the radial displacement i.e.
$$
tan\beta = \frac{rd\theta}{dr}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The solution starts with the Cartesian coordinates
$$
x=r\cos\theta=a e^{b\theta}\cos\theta \, , \qquad 
y=r\sin\theta=a e^{b\theta}\sin\theta
$$
for a spiral given by the polar equation $r(\theta)=ae^{b\theta}$.

Constructing the vector $\vec r=
(a e^{b\theta}\cos\theta,a e^{b\theta}\sin\theta,0)$
we find the tangent vector $d\vec \ell$ by taking the derivative of $\vec r$ w/r to the parameter $\theta$:
$$
d\vec \ell
=\left(a b e^{b \theta } \cos (\theta )-a e^{b \theta } \sin (\theta ),a b e^{b \theta }
   \sin (\theta )+a e^{b \theta } \cos (\theta ),0\right)d\theta \, .
$$
Then it follows that
\begin{align}
ds^2&=d\vec\ell\cdot d\vec \ell=
a^2 \left(b^2+1\right) e^{2 b \theta }(d\theta)^2=r^2(\theta)(1+b^2)
(d\theta)^2\,  ,\\
&=r^2(\theta)\left(1+\frac{(dr/d\theta)^2}{r^2(\theta)}\right)(d\theta)^2\, .
\end{align}
Since
$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=b r $
we also have 
$$
(r d\theta)^2= \left(\frac{dr}{b}\right)^2
$$
and thus
$$
ds^2= \left(\frac{dr}{b}\right)^2+ (dr)^2= (dr)^2\left(1+\frac{1}{b^2}\right)
$$
Finally,
\begin{align}
\vec r\cdot d\vec \ell&= r d\ell \cos\beta  = a^2 b e^{2b\theta}d\theta\, ,\\
\vert \vec r\times d\vec \ell \vert &=r d\ell \sin\beta = a^2 e^{2b\theta}
d\theta
\end{align}
so that
$$
\tan(\beta)=\frac{1}{b}\, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

While considering infinitesmals or differential lengths, $d \theta \approx 0$ or in other words OS is parallel to OQ.

In the small right differential triangle SPQ the Pythagoras thm holds and can be drawn as given and is often helpful. ( You already labeled $dr,$ so continue) .. $\beta$ is the *same* alternate angle between parallels.

$$ \cos\beta=\frac {dr}{ ds}, \quad \tan \beta =\frac{PQ}{PS}=\frac{r \; d \theta}{dr} ,\quad \sin \beta =\frac{PQ}{QS}=\frac{r \; d \theta}{ds} ; $$

General log spiral has equation

$$ r = r_{ start } \cdot e ^ {(\cot \alpha \;\theta)} $$

In this particular equiangular case $\alpha = \pi/4 = \beta $